# PsychoPy 1.84.1 crashes in previously-running script

Tags: psychopy

I have a script to run an experiment that presents stimuli and records keyboard answers. The script was running normally in the previous version of PsychoPy (1.83), but since upgrading to 1.84.1, the script crashes right after the instructions screen (where the block type is selected and the first trial is presented), with the follwing error:

```
###### Running: D:\Experiments\Imagery\Tasks\2.MRI\imageryMRI_lastrun.py #######
pyo version 0.8.0 (uses single precision)
FreeType import Failed: Freetype library not found
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Experiments\Imagery\Tasks\2.MRI\imageryMRI_lastrun.py", line 648, in <module>
    units='norm')
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\PsychoPy2\lib\site-packages\psychopy-1.84.1-py2.7.egg\psychopy\contrib\lazy_import.py", line 120, in __call__
    return obj(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\PsychoPy2\lib\site-packages\psychopy-1.84.1-py2.7.egg\psychopy\visual\textbox\__init__.py", line 376, in __init__
    self._font_name = fm.getFontFamilyStyles()[0][0]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Sometimes the script crashes right after running it (pressing Ctrl+R), whereas other times it gets to the initial (instructions) screen and only crashes after the spacebar is pressed there to continue.

Googling the terms above did not find anything helpful. I checked all routines&components again and can find nothing that would be problematic and lead to a crash. I uploaded my script [here](http://www.2shared.com/file/yPNqXwtR/imageryMRI.html) in case anyone is able to have a look. Many thanks for any help.

Comment: Given the error "FreeType import Failed: Freetype library not found": where is your freetype library?

Comment: I searched the PsychoPy folder for that term and found the file c:\Program Files (x86)\PsychoPy2\Lib\site-packages\pyglet\font\freetype.py

Comment: But no binary library, which is what I'd expect. It's hard to tell which dependency (pyglet? psychopy?) relies on freetype, but you'll need to install the freetype library.

Comment: Actually (sorry) there are also other files with this name, such as freetype_lib.py. As I said the script was running fine in the previous version, which would have had the same default libraries

Comment: there is also a c:\Program Files (x86)\PsychoPy2\Lib\site-packages\wx-3.0-msw\wx\freetype6.dll

Comment: what's also strange is that sometimes the script crashes right after running it (pressing Ctrl+R), whereas other times it gets to the initial (instructions) screen and only crashes after the spacebar is pressed there to continue